# HttpModule not running with Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, httpmodule, cassini

I am using an HttpModule to do some URL shortening on my site. I am using Visual Studio 2008 and IIS 7, and .Net 3.5.

When the module is specified in the **system.webServer** element of web.config, and the site is run in IIS, it works fine. The config looks like this:

```
<system.webServer>
        <modules>
            <add name="MinimizeModule" type="ClipperHouse.UrlMinimizer.MinimizeModule" />
        </modules>...
```

My module attaches to the BeginRequest event, everything works. However, I can't get it to run using the built-in VS web server (Cassini). I tried moving the module config to the **system.web** element in web.config, no luck. I put a breakpoint on it, nothing happens.

Any thoughts on why this would be an issue?

(I also tried the Application_BeginRequest event in global.asax. Still no luck, though I'd prefer to keep everything in web.config anyway.)

Answer (score 41):

Cassini, the development web server provided with IIS uses the IIS6 module syntax, so you must duplicate the module add like so

```
<system.web>
  <httpModules>
    <add name="MinimizeModule" type="ClipperHouse.UrlMinimizer.MinimizeModule" />
  </httpModules>
</system.web>


<system.webServer>
  <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
  <modules>
    <remove name="MinimizeModule" />
    <add name="MinimizeModule" type="ClipperHouse.UrlMinimizer.MinimizeModule" 
         preCondition="managedHandler" />
  </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

Note that I've also added a precondition to your IIS7 settings

Comment: tried this. My module .ctors and Init()s but any attempt to attach event handlers is met with PlatformNotSupportedException - Cassini seems to totally ignore the IIS7 section.

Comment: Well yes, Cassini does - you have to add the IIS6 syntax too, hence having both there

Comment: Thanks for this - I had the problem the other way round and was going slightly crazy.  I would count this as an IIS bug myself: either it is registered (in which case I shouldn't need to register it again) or it isn't registered (in which case I shouldn't need to remove it before registering it again!).  But that's another issue.  Main thing is it works now.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you are running on IIS 7, put the module in:

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
      <modules>
         <add name="MinimizeModule" type="ClipperHouse.UrlMinimizer.MinimizeModule" />
      </modules>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

If you are running on Cassini (Visual Studio's integrated miniature web-server), put the module in:

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
      <httpModules>
          <add name="MinimizeModule" type="ClipperHouse.UrlMinimizer.MinimizeModule" />
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```

IIS will crash if you give it the Cassini location.
Cassini will crash if you give it the IIS location.

Whenever i deploy, i have to be sure not to deploy `web.config`. i also include the notes in `web.config`:

```
<system.web>
   <!--The Cassini location to add modules (comment out for IIS)-->
   <httpModules>
      <!--WARNING: IIS will crash if you leave this in here.
          IISBUG: IIS doesn't support system.web/httpModules, 
          and Cassini doesn't support system.webServer/modules
      -->
      <!--Comment out for IIS-->
      <add name="PerformanceHttpModule" type="DummyPlaceholder.PerformanceHttpModule"/>
   </httpModules>
</system.web>

<system.webServer>
   <!--The IIS7 location to add modules (comment out for Cassini)
   <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <!--IIS7 will crash if you present a system.web httpModules. -->
      <remove name="PerformanceHttpModule" />
      <add name="PerformanceHttpModule" type="DummyPlaceholder.PerformanceHttpModule"/>
   </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

IIS's left hand doesn't know what Cassini's right hand is doing - and they both screwed it up.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try also putting the module declaration in the  element? When running in dev using Cassini, that's usually the place I have to put modules to get them running.

Comment: Could you expand on this further?  I'm not sure what you mean.