# Should i declare https in web.config?

Tags: security, https, web-config

I think i am missing something in https...

Currently i am using this to redirect the desired page from http to https

```
  If Not Request.IsSecureConnection Then
  Dim serverName As String = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Request.ServerVariables("SERVER_NAME"))
  Dim filePath As String = Request.FilePath
  Response.Redirect(("https://" & serverName) + filePath)
  End If
```

Should i declare somewhere in the web.config the absolut links for https?

p.s. My links are relative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write an [HttpModule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120190/c-how-to-determine-if-https/1120294#1120294) and add it to the web.config.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a static URL then you can add this in your web config:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="url" value="http://www.yoursite.com" />
</appSettings>
```

And after that you can get that value where ever you want like this:

```
string strHost = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("url").ToString();
```

Hope this will solve your problem.