# Deny code execution IIS7 with web.config

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, web-config, authorization, iis-7.5

I want to block users run specific extensions in an upload folder (/assets/public/) of a web application. Users can upload image files which are also re-sized during the upload. But for more security I want to deny scripts like aspx, asp, php...

I have current code which blocks every extension but I want to allow extensions like .jpg:

```
<location path="assets/public">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <deny users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
</system.webServer>
```

Also users do not have FTP access and application is pre-compiled.

Comment: Do you mean a hosting case? When user using local Web.config registers own extension to use?

Comment: Users have granted upload access only to assets/public folder and customer has no FTP. I don't want user or hackers to be able to run remote scripts.

Comment: Please post some  user's supposed config for hack

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<httpModules>
    <clear />
</httpModules>
```

or

```
<location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
</location>
```

Comment: "An ASP.NET setting has been detected that does not apply in Integrated managed pipeline mode." error after first option and second one not working.

Comment: @Hasan: See [this qeestion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209999/an-asp-net-setting-has-been-detected-that-does-not-apply-in-integrated-managed-pi) regarding the first issue

Answer (score -2):

Here is how I solved this with global.asax and routing. Just added these rules:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("any", "assets/public/{file}.{ext}", "~/e/404.aspx");
routes.MapPageRoute("any-sub","assets/public/{sub}/{file}.{ext}","~/e/404.aspx");

routes.Ignore("{any}.jpg");
routes.Ignore("{any}.png");
routes.Ignore("{any}.gif");
routes.Ignore("{any}.pdf");
```