# Websharper configuration on IIS 7.5

Tags: f#, iis-7.5, websharper

Does anyone know how to configure Websharper 1.0 or 2 (sitelets) on IIS 7.5?

This helps on IIS Express at least
[An ASP.NET setting has been detected that does not apply in Integrated managed pipeline mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209999/an-asp-net-setting-has-been-detected-that-does-not-apply-in-integrated-managed-pi)

Comment: Have you tried something ? If yes, what error you got?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested WebSharper 2.2 sitelets on IIS 7.5. I could see a problem with no sitelets showing up (404) when deploying to a virtual directory (both IIS 7.5 and the development server), but a root deployment worked as expected. WebSharper 2.3 due for release today fixes this virtual directory deployment bug. I hope that was it, but I would be interested to learn more details if the bug persists. Thanks! --A

Comment: The release is out at http://websharper.com - do you still have problems with this version? Thanks!

Comment: My licence has expired so I can't try it. Could you backport it to 1.0.