# error while executing SSIS package with web service task

Tags: web-services, ssis

Description: An error occurred with the following error message: "Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.WebServiceTask.WebserviceTaskException: The Web Service threw an error during method execution. The error is: Client found response content type of 'text/html; charset=utf-8', but expected 'text/xml'.  The request failed with the error message:  --           IIS 7.5 Detailed Error - 500.24 - Internal Server Error

## Server Error in Application "DEFAULT WEB SITE"

Internet Information Services 7.5

Error Summary

### HTTP Error 500.24 - Internal Server Error

#### An ASP.NET setting has been detected that does not apply in Integrated managed pipeline mode.

Detailed Error Information

Comment: Have a look at the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209999/an-asp-net-setting-has-been-detected-that-does-not-apply-in-integrated-managed-p

Comment: i have tried everything, i didn't help me. pls help

Answer (score 0):

Change your application pool properties to:

```
.NET Framework Version
-- .NET Framework *version*

Pipeline Mode
-- Classic
```

Answer (score 0):

change your web.config like this:

```
<system.webServer> 
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" /> 
</system.webServer>
```