# HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name is null

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, httpcontext

I'm trying to use HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name to get the user's Windows login details from the internal network, however it's empty.

I've tried changing the authentication mode in Web.Config with no joy:

```
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
```

I've also heard that in the project properties you should enable Windows authentication and disable anonymous authentication like so:

[image]

But then I get a re-direct loop, with the message "This webpage has a redirect loop" in Chrome.

I've also checked that Windows Authentication is installed on my machine:

[image]

Any ideas on how to fix this please?

Many thanks

Comment: Are you using this method while user login: FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie("user name",true);

Comment: Thank you, I've just tried adding that into my Home Controller but unfortunately I still get the same error

Comment: please try with default settings(as you have  modified them)

Comment: This is working for me:
  @if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {

            <strong>@Html.Encode(User.Identity.Name)</strong>
            @Html.ActionLink("Sign Out", "Logout", "Home")

        }

Comment: Thanks, I've just tried <strong>@Html.Encode(User.Identity.Name)</strong> and it's null again :(

Comment: I think we have some problem with 'Windows authentication'.

Comment: Yes, I've created a system in WebForms before and it worked fine... it's very odd that it isn't working now

Comment: If it's on your local workstation, you might want to try setting the <identity impersonate="true" />

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately I now get an 'An ASP.NET setting has been detected that does not apply in Integrated managed pipeline mode.' error.

Answer (score 7):

When I have:

```
<authentication mode="Windows"/>
<identity impersonate="true/>
```

in web.config I get the current user with:

```
string currUser = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.ToString();
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply, however I get the following error:

_An ASP.NET setting has been detected that does not apply in Integrated managed pipeline mode.

Most likely causes:
system.web/identity@impersonate is set to true._

Comment: Further to the above, I got rid of the error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209999/an-asp-net-setting-has-been-detected-that-does-not-apply-in-integrated-managed-p

However unfortunately the value `System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name` of is still null :(

Answer (score 0):

Changing my project web server settings to `Local IIS` instead of `IIS Express` resolved the issue for me, though I'm not sure why this is the case if anyone has additional information about this.

- Right click the project
- Click Properties
- Go to the Web tab
- In the Servers section, select `Local IIS` from the dropdown