# Smart card authorization in web form

Tags: c#

how to set up smart-card authorization in web form
i can read ATR of smart card...

```
try {
    m_iCard.Connect( DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text, SHARE.Shared, PROTOCOL.T0orT1);
    try {
        // Get the ATR of the card
        byte[] atrValue = m_iCard.GetAttribute(SCARD_ATTR_VALUE.ATR_STRING);
    } catch {

    }
} catch {

}
```

But further from that no idea.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the authentication process in place? If not, you can access the link below, it has a tutorial for that:
http://securitythroughabsurdity.com/2007/04/implementing-smartcardauthenticationmod.html

Once the users were authenticated by the SM, you can authorize them:
http://securitythroughabsurdity.com/2007/04/implementing-authorization-in-aspnet.html

You can see on this link the full tutorial:
http://securitythroughabsurdity.com/2007/04/implementing-smartcard-authentication.html

Edited - it’s possible to implement authorization on the following forms:

Declarative

```
using System.Security.Permissions;
...
[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role="Administrator"),
PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role="Auditors")]
public void DoSomethingImportant()
{
...
}
```

Imperative

```
using System.Security.Permissions;
...
public void DoSomethingImportant()
{
PrincipalPermission permCheck = new PrincipalPermission(Nothing, "Administrators");
permCheck.Demand();
}
```

IPrincipal.IsInRole() Check

```
if (myPrincipal.IsInRole("Administrators")
{
...
}
```

Web.Config - Specify access permissions to files and/or folders in the web.config

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
...
</system.web>
<location path="Admin">
<system.web>
<authorization>
<allow roles="Administrator" />
<deny users="*" />
</authorization>
</system.web>
</location>
<location path="Reports">
<system.web>
<authorization>
<allow roles="Auditor" />
<deny users="*" />
</authorization>
</system.web>
</location>
</configuration>
```

Comment: i tried with that but i get the error HTTP Error 500.22 - Internal Server Error
An ASP.NET setting has been detected that does not apply in Integrated managed pipeline mode.

Comment: Jagrit - there is a SO answer for the problem that you're having http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209999/an-asp-net-setting-has-been-detected-that-does-not-apply-in-integrated-managed-p