# An ASP.NET setting has been detected that does not apply in Integrated managed pipeline mode.(the project does not even run locally)

Tags: c#, .net, iis

This same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209999/an-asp-net-setting-has-been-detected-that-does-not-apply-in-integrated-managed-p) was posted in the site and the suggested answer was to use.

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

but adding the above mentioned line does not solve the issue.

**Most likely cause**

- This application defines configuration in the system.web/httpHandlers
  section.

And

```
Module     ConfigurationValidationModule
Notification       BeginRequest
Handler    ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0
Error Code     0x80070032
```

moreover my project does not seem to load locally as well, where as the question i mentioned earlier worked fine locally.

How do i Solve this error?

Thank you in advance. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [An ASP.NET setting has been detected that does not apply in Integrated managed pipeline mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209999/an-asp-net-setting-has-been-detected-that-does-not-apply-in-integrated-managed-p)

Comment: @stuartd i tried the solution in the link u suggested and it doesn't seem to solve the problem, apart from that, the link u shared explicitly says it works locally, mine does not even work locally. i captioned the question same way since that is the error i get... anyways 
thank you.. :)

Comment: There are several long and detailed answers to that question, which contain lots of options, fixes and workarounds. Have you tried all of them?

Comment: I have tried all possible scenarios i came across in stack overflow and in other forums..... solutions like changing IIS to classic mode and integration mode.

Comment: So you are running under a Classic app pool and you still get the error?

Comment: I was running under classic ap pool  n I got the error, so I changed to integrated and it still gives error @stuartd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing the following line from the web.config file fixed the issue for me.

```
<system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="*.less" verb="GET" type="dotless.Core.LessCssHttpHandler, dotless.Core" />
    </httpHandlers>
  </system.web>
```