# HTTP Error 500.22 - Internal Server Error - MVC 5 Application From IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, networking, iis-7.5, web-deployment

I am really stuck with an issue in my MVC 5 application from IIS 7.5 sever. Application works fine in my local developing environment but it failed in server. I am sure that the issue is related to URL routing. I can sea my application home page but if i take some link(Link to any application route(Page)), then IIS is showing 500.22 issues.

I tried many solution to fix this issue.

1- Changed mode from Integrated to Classic

2- Added some patches mentioned in https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/980368

3- validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"

Finally i installed MVC in my server machine also. Still no hope. Keep getting 500.22 error in case of route. I added some log writing functionality but i coudn't find any log related to that. In case of routing something else happen from IIS.

I am really stuck with issue. If anyone know any info related to this. then please help me.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [An ASP.NET setting has been detected that does not apply in Integrated managed pipeline mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209999/an-asp-net-setting-has-been-detected-that-does-not-apply-in-integrated-managed-p)

Comment: I tried <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/> also. Updated my quetion

Comment: It will be better if you show your route configuration.