# validcfg.dll failed to load but validation set to false

Tags: asp.net, iis, dll

I am trying to migrate an IIS server and a web application to my machine.

I've imported the settings from another machine, but some .dll failed to load.

I've just installed them, but now I stuck.

> The Module DLL C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\validcfg.dll failed to
>   load.  The data is the error.

What I really want to do is to install this dll I just do not know, what should I install from windows services.

Under IIS there is no ConfigurationValidationModule or any like this.

Of course I've tried to goole it, and found this [SO topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209999/an-asp-net-setting-has-been-detected-that-does-not-apply-in-integrated-managed-p).

The only occure is in IIS_schema.xml and I rewrote it to false.

```
<sectionSchema name="system.webServer/validation">
  <attribute name="validateIntegratedModeConfiguration" type="bool" defaultValue="false" />
</sectionSchema>
```

I just changed the `Managed Pipline` to `Classic` in my application pool to through IIS management console.

Restarted the IIS, but I am still getting 503, and in the Event Viewer the error appears again.

Can anybody help me with this?

**EDIT**

All the Health and Diagnostic modules are installed, but there is no file like this.

Answer (score 0):

I've just unistall IIS and WAS (Windows Process Activation Service), reinstall IIS and WAS and after this everything was fine.

`validcfg.dll` is a core module of Health And Diagnostic.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem, but found out it happened because i copied an existing configuration file from another server i run to the new server.. the other server had asp.net installed and running, and my new server had not..

so there propably was a config fault and iis didnt like that..

after installing the missing component on the server everything went just fine..