# IHttpHandler is not getting called on MVC controller action method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2, httphandler, ihttphandler

I have defined a custom HTTP handler, to update the request header. But when I am calling http://localhost:52705/Home/Index. my custom HTTP handler is not getting called for that controller -> action request. I implemented as follow

```
public class TestHandler :  IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        return;
    }

    public bool IsReusable { get; private set; }
}
```

also, find the web.cofing entry for HTTPHandler

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="TestHandler" type=" mvc_app.Handler.TestHandler" path="*" verb="*"/>      
    </handlers>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
```

Comment: does it called somewhere else? the `path="*"` is a bit tricky. since handlers are **endpoint**, process requests and done with it.

Comment: Register your handler in `<httpHandlers></httpHandlers>` under `<system.web>`

Comment: @BagusTesa I don't know what should I provide in path="*" as we need to call HTTP handler on MVC controller action method

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Thanks I did the same but I am getting HTTP Error 500.23 - Internal Server Error - Module    ConfigurationValidationModule
Notification    BeginRequest
Handler    ExtensionlessUrl-Integrated-4.0
Error Code    0x80070032

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209999/an-asp-net-setting-has-been-detected-that-does-not-apply-in-integrated-managed-p

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Thanks I found a solution please check it out my answer

Answer (score 1):

After spending one day if found one trick to achieve the same functionality as I want to implement using IHttpModule

Add custom HTTP module

```
public class TestModule : IHttpModule
{
    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.BeginRequest += OnBeginRequest;
    }

    static void OnBeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs a)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("OnBeginRequest Called MVC");        
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Update web.config to register custom HTTP module

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <add name="TestModule" type="mvc_app.Handler.TestModule"/>          
    </modules>
 </system.webServer>
```

for the above solution still, I am trying to figure it out why my OnBeginRequest() method is getting called twice