# Newly created AspNet Core web api app throws HTTP Error 500.24

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I've created a new aspnet core web api app and when I run it and it takes me to a sample api page (/api/values) I get the following error page:

> HTTP Error 500.24 - Internal Server Error
>
> An ASP.NET setting has been detected that does not apply in Integrated managed pipeline mode.
>
> Most likely causes: system.web/identity@impersonate is set to true.

Literally nothing has been added or changed from the default app.
Similar app I created a week or so ago works fine.
Deleting and re-creating a new web app doesn't help.

dotnet core version is 2.2, Visual Studio 2017 15.9.2, Windows 10

Comment: How did you run this project, from VS or hosted in IIS? Check [An ASP.NET setting has been detected that does not apply in Integrated managed pipeline mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209999/an-asp-net-setting-has-been-detected-that-does-not-apply-in-integrated-managed-p)

Comment: @TaoZhou From VS. It runs fine if I run it using dotnet run. Also since it's a aspnet core app it doesn't even have web.config.

Comment: You could manually add this web.config.

Comment: My experience is that deploying with WebDeploy, a web.config is created for you.  If not, as Tao suggested, create one.  I have three environments to deploy to.  The first time through one was functional and the other two had the HTTP Error 500.19.  Uninstalling and reinstalling the SDKs and the dotnet-hosting package brought me to the HTTP Error 500.24 on the other two.  Thrashing around with uninstalls and reinstalls "fixed???" one of the remaining two.  Finally, adding the <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/> directive to the third one got that working. This is BS, MS.

Comment: Has this been fixed? I'm running into this issue with the project that builds on one machine but not on another.