# How do I configure my WCF (svc) Service on IIS to serve on HTTPS requests only?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, iis, ssl

I have a WCF (svs) web service, that is running on a Windows 2008 IIS web server.

The IIS server already has a SSL certificate installed and is hosting Classic ASP, and PHP over both HTTP and HTTPS.

I have installed the WCF service as a application on the IIS server (on the same domain) and it can serve requests using both HTTP and HTTPS perfectly.

However, I want this WCF service to ONLY serve HTTPS requests and responses.

What do I need to change within the WCF web.config to achieve this ?

**UPDATE**

Following on from my post above, I've managed to research the following which appears to work using the web.config file;

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
     <service behaviorConfiguration="returnFaults" name="MyService.MonitorService">
      <endpoint binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration=
            "TransportSecurity" contract="MyService.IMonitorSvc" />
     </service>
   </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="returnFaults">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
        <wsHttpBinding>
           <binding name="TransportSecurity">
                 <security mode="Transport">
                  <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
                  </security>
            </binding>
          </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Can anyone confirm that this is the correct approach for a WCF service, to enforce that all requests are made via HTTPS (SSL) ?

Basically using the above, would a user be able to make a HTTP request to the service or not ?  Or would the service always enforce HTTPS

Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Use the IIS URL Redirect to match all http:// requests and redirect to https:// ?

Comment: My preference is to NOT enforce HTTPS within IIS, since if I move the service to another domain, I need to configure IIS again, and it could be something that is forgotten to be done. I prefer to do it in the code/web.config somehow

Comment: The IIS URL Redirect just appends a <rewrite> node to your application's web.config file, so it should be easily portable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Microsoft URL Rewrite module](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) and then add the following into your web.config file:

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <clear />
            <rule name="Redirect to https" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

If this isn't acceptable (as you will have to remember to add this module in other deployments), then [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1120294/977032) points out how to write your own https redirector.

I'm not completely sure about it, but you might be able to use `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.IsSecureConnection` to check within your actual code as well.